# How to read table schema information from SQL server in C++ Qt?

Tags: sql-server, database, qt, sqlite, information-schema

I'm working on a project that migrate Microsoft SQL Server to SQLite. I need to read table schema definitions from SQL Server. Then create a same structure database in SQLite.

I can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` in Microsoft Database Management Studio to get detailed definitions. But when I use it in Qt, complains an error:

```
QSqlError(208, "QODBC3: Unable to execute statement", "[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'.")
```

Could anyone tell me how to read schema information in Qt?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I did it. I used the following query in C++ Qt to get the columns detailed definitions such as name, data type, length.

SELECT c.name AS column_nam,t.name AS type_name,c.max_length FROM sys.columns AS c JOIN sys.types AS t ON c.user_type_id=t.user_type_id WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('your_table_name')